# Can somebody access my router from outside the network?

Tags: security, remote-access, router

I've discovered that my uncle has a default login and password on his router.

I want to convince him to change it and thus I want to collect some arguments. For now my only argument is that a cracker can break his WiFi password and then mess up with the router.

So, is it possible that cracker can access his router from outside his LAN? Let's assume the cracker didn't break the WiFi password but is in a close proximity to the router - e.g. a neighbour.

I'll add that "Remote Config Management" is turned off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, one can access the router from outside the network. Let me explain you how to do it.

Case #1 :

Lets assume that at least one client is connected to your uncle's Router. So you can deauthenticate their signals using tools like **aircrack-ng** to sniff the password from the packets which are going from client to your uncle's router. Now you can use a custom wordlist to crack the password in the captured packet file. By doing this you can connect to your uncle's router.

Case #2 :

But if you want to get administrator rights for your Uncle's router you can use a tool called **Reaver** . You will be needing an *External Wi-Fi Adapter*  to work out on this tool. This will be cracking the PIN of the router which can't be changed, so you can get access your uncles router from outside of the network as you are now having the login details of his router.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! Tbh, though, I didn't understand the 2nd case. I thought that there's only 1 account (and 1 role = admin) on router. So when I buy a router and I log in with admin/admin I don't have administrator rights? My 2nd question is what do I need the adapter for? Do I have to plug it in my computer or the router? If it's the latter, the argument won't work because WiFi password is written on the router anyway, so...

Comment: @mr_jigsaw
Let me clarify each of them in the same order:
1) You can login to your router using the normal method and also you can login using the PIN which you can view on the router.
2) Of course you do have admin privilages but you have to configure your router properly.
3) You would need an <i> external wifi adapter </i> while cracking the PIN of the router because your system's wifi adapter is'nt capable of doing that work.
4) You have to attach it to the USB port of your PC , because that will be doing the cracking job, while consistently concentrating on single channel.